# Win 10 displays wrong location

Tags: windows-10, browser, geolocation

## Windows 10 has my location wrong (by 70 km).

- I have correctly set "default location" in Win 10 settings. It is not being used and is most probably overriden by "exact location" algorithm.
- Public geoIP locators on the web give better position than Win 10.
- Google Chrome provides correct location (see below).

**How do I achieve getting correct location in different applications on Win 10?**

### Wrong location in

- Windows 10 Maps
- Microsoft Edge (both Google Maps and Bing Maps)
- Internet Explorer (both Google Maps and Bing Maps)
- Firefox (both Google Maps and Bing Maps)

### Correct location in

- Google Chrome (both Google Maps and Bing Maps)

Comment: How Chrome does geolocation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633621/how-does-chrome-know-my-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can geolocate you exactly from your IP address.
The most that can be deduced is your nearest ISP node.

Evidently, the nearest ISP node is at 70 km from your home.

See Wikipedia
[Service tiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet#Service_tiers).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. I am not asking about IP geolocation. My goal is to get Win 10 location feature working. IP geolocation is just one way how to do it. As I wrote, IP geolocation on public websites is much more precise than Win 10 location. Apart from that, Win 10 has more ways to detect location, like position of WiFi networks. Google used to be scanning WiFis and then use their known locations in their algorithms. If Win 10 does nothing like this (and thier geoIP is worse then average) then their location feature is pretty useless. So to the question - can it be fixed?

Comment: Some apps do geolocation much better than Windows. Google Maps does it very well on my computer, Bing Maps too. You may test if these websites also get it wrong for your location, and if they do then the data they are using for your wifi location is erroneous.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have tested multiple map services in different web browsers and their behavior was slightli different - I then came to a good-enough answear, at least for me. I would appreciate your comments to my answer, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot fix Win 10 geolocation.

It is limited by design.

## But... you can disable it for desktop applications.

- With disabled access to the Win 10 location, desktop applications (like web browsers) will have to use their own algorithms (usually much better) for determining location.

Simply turn off Win 10 location sharing for desktop apps.

> Windows 10 Settings -> Privacy -> Location

[image: Win 10 Settings - Location sharing for Desktop apps]

---

## Real World Testing

I have tested how things work in different browsers and these are my results.

### Mozilla Firefox (version 86.0)

- Firefox uses Win 10 location if available (in the above mentioned settings).
- Else it uses Google Geolocation API.
- Firefox can also use Mozilla Geolocation API if instructed to do so via about:config (geo.provider.network.url).

### Google Chrome (version 88.0.4324.190)

- Chrome is not impacted by Win 10 geolocation at all. It just uses Google Geolocation API no matter what.

### Microsoft Edge (version 89.0.774.45)

- Edge seems to use the same geolocation algorithm as Win 10 so it always produces the same results as with Win 10 location.

### Windows 10 Maps app (version 10.2101.9.0)

- This keeps using Win 10 location as the setting mentioned above impacts only desktop apps, but Windows 10 is an Microsoft Store app, not a desktop app.